# Mocha does not seem wait for promise chain to complete before running test

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, sequelize.js, mocha.js

I am using Mocha to test data base interactions in my code (so I cannot mock the database).
For the tests to work I want to clean up my database before each test. According to my research I should be using Mocha's ability to handle promises being returned by the before function.

Here is how I am trying to achieve this:

```
const Orm = require('../db');

describe('Loading Xml Files to Database should work', () => {
  before(() => {
    return Orm.models.File.destroy({force: true, truncate: true, cascade: true});
  });
  
  it('run test', () => {
          loadXmlFileToDatabase(....);    // this loads data from a 
                                          //  file into the table "files"
          Orm.Orm.query("SELECT * FROM files")
            .then(function (result){
              console.log(result);
            })
            .catch(function(error){
              console.log(error);
            });
      });
});
```

I am, however getting zero rows back from my Query at the end of the code. If I omit the `before()` function everything wrks, so my conclusion is, that for some reason Mocha is not waiting for it to complete.

How do I make sure, the `before()` function completes, before my test is run?

Comment: Should work. Your `it` test itself however does not wait for the promise it creates.

Comment: You got me Bergi, where is "it" creating a promise?

Comment: The promise from `Orm.Orm.query()` needs to be returned for mocha to wait.

Comment: probably need to wait for `loadXmlFileToDatabase()` as well.

Comment: @MischaObrecht `Orm.query` does create and return a promise (which you are using with `then` and `catch`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocha expects a promise to be returned by a function for it to wait.
Either explicitly `return` a promise from plain functions or use `async` functions that `await`

```
describe('Loading Xml Files to Database should work', function(){

  before(async function(){
    await Orm.models.File.destroy({force: true, truncate: true, cascade: true});
  });
  
  it('run test', async function(){
    await loadXmlFileToDatabase(....);    // this loads data from a 
                                          //  file into the table "files"
    const result = await Orm.Orm.query("SELECT * FROM files");
    expect(result).to.eql({})
  })

});
```